# how to do such calculation task in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
                 disc       val
a            -1.140502       1
b            -0.916104       2
c            -0.828460       3
d            -2.828460       4
e            -2.238450       5
```

I would like to get the a result dataframe like

```
                 disc       val     final
a            -1.140502       1       1
b            -0.916104       2       2 
c            -0.828460       3       6
d            -2.828460       4       24 
e            -2.238450       5       120
```

Comment: Please show some researches and tries. Include your current code and why you think you are failing.

Comment: I'm a pandas newbie. the only way I know is to do a for loop like such :for i in range(df.shape[0]): do the caculation and fill the data. however this is so slow and ugly. I'm wondering if there is any easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [17]: df.val.cumprod()
Out[17]:
a      1
b      2
c      6
d     24
e    120
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you max. I googled 30minutes without the proper answer, but you helped me out with only one line.